# Global paste values for excel

Tags: excel, global-variables, vba

The following code is for a Paste Value only event. And it works when the values are moved between the same sheet. However if I copy a value from a different workbook and run the macro, Excel complains that the data is out of range. How does one go about making a global paste-value macro that operates over the entire excel program?

```
 Sub PasteValOnly()
'
' PasteValOnly Macro
' pastes values only
'
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. If I create Book1 and Book2, paste your code in Book2, copy data from Book1, activate Book2 and run your code it does what you would expect...

Comment: @assylias: It doesn't (Not sure why) if it is different Excel instances

Comment: @SiddharthRout No - you can't copy paste values accross instances, you would have to select Text (as you do in your answer). I thought the OP meant 2 workbooks within the same instance of Excel.

Comment: @assylias: Yes I am aware that you cannot :) But Why exactly? That I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And put the macro in your PERSONAL.XLSB, this way it will always work.

This is what I use:

```
'GENERIC MACROS
Sub GxPasteValuesOnly() 'Assigned to Ctrl+Shift+v
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, skipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= False
```